# android - myAttributes parameter in progress wheel library library

Tags: android

I want to use progress wheel library defined here https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel.

```
 ProgressWheel pw = new ProgressWheel(myContext, myAttributes);
```

What is the meaning of myAttributes. It is somwthing related to the activity? thanks

Comment: myAttributes are the attributes from the xml file where the view is defined. Ex: android:paddingLeft="10dp" ;

Comment: but it should be instaed of using xml. no?

Comment: exactlly , But after i've seen how the view is implemented i recomand that you add the view in the xml not programatically .